# Import BLOB formatted csv with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a csv file that is an output from a BLOB store. The csv contains 6 related entries. Not all records utilise the 6 tables but all records do use table 1. I would like to import table 1 into a data frame, ultimately to write this into postgres. Data is described as following

> Files are ASCII text files comprising variable length fields delimited by an asterisk. The files have an extension of “csv”. Records are separated by a Carriage Return/Line Feed. No data items should contain an asterisk.

Further information is given in the technical arrangement.

> Technical Arrangement
>
> The technical arrangement of our summary data is as follows:
>     Fields are in the exact order in which they are listed in this file specification.
>     Records are broken down into Types. Each Type represents a different part of the record.
>     Each record will begin with Type ‘01’ data
>     For each record type ‘01’, there is one or more record type ‘02’s containing Survey Line Item data.   There may be zero or more of record types ’03’ and '06'.
>     There may be zero or one of record types '04' and '05'.
>     If a record type '06' exists, there will be one record type '07'
>     The end of a record is only indicated by the next row of Type ‘01’ data or the end of the file.
>   You should use this information to read the file into formal data structures.

I understand I could use java in place of python but I am more familiar with the python syntax

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at step one, simply getting the csv into python using `Data = pd.read_csv(voacsv,sep='*', header=None, dtype=object)`  throws a huge error. I've adjusted the delimiter to match the spec but think its due to the nested records being separated by another separator

Comment: If i can get the csv in then i think i can use python to pull the data apart and feed it into tables.

Comment: Your question could be improved by adding some example data, desired output, your code and the exact error it produces. As it is I highly doubt you can get any useful responses.